# Open another conection in OracleDataReader loop the oracle session not close

Tags: c#, oracle, session, odp.net

I have a problem about session not close when make calling another connection under OracleDataReader loop code below

```
    private ArrayList GetORA()
    {          
        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
        string connectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=xx)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)));User ID=kcdev2usr;Password=password;ENLIST=FALSE;Pooling=true;Max Pool Size=20;";
        const string queryString = "select * from MASTER_TABLE";
        using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        {
            OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(queryString, connection);
            connection.Open();
            OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            try
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Master m = new Master();
                    m.ID = reader["ID"].ToString();
                    m.obj = GetAnother(reader["SOME"].ToString());
                    arr.Add(m);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                reader.Close();
            }

        }

        return arr;
    }


    private Object GetAnother(string some)
    {
        // Do something         
        string getNextID = PutSome(some);
        //=====
        Object obj = null;
        string connectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=xx)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)));User ID=kcdev2usr;Password=password;ENLIST=FALSE;Pooling=true;Max Pool Size=20;";
        const string queryString = "SELECT PAGE_NAME FROM ANOTHER_TABLE WHERE ID=:ID";
        using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        {
            OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(queryString, connection);
            command.Parameters.Add("ID",getNextID);
            connection.Open();
            OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            try
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    obj = CreateObj(dr["PAGE_NAME"].ToString());
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }
```

[session is not close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZPK5.jpg)

Then,.. I've try to move the problem method out loop like this

```
private ArrayList GetORA()
    {          
        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
        string connectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=xx)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)));User ID=kcdev2usr;Password=password;ENLIST=FALSE;Pooling=true;Max Pool Size=20;";
        const string queryString = "select * from MASTER_TABLE";
        using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        {
            OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(queryString, connection);
            connection.Open();
            OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            try
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Master m = new Master();
                    m.ID = reader["ID"].ToString(); 
                    m.Some = reader["SOME"].ToString();                     
                    arr.Add(m);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
           foreach (var item in arr)
           {
                item.obj = GetAnother(item.Some);
           }
        }

        return arr;
    }
```

All oracle session was clean and clear correctly, why?

- I thing my code not good to be but I would like to know what difference about ODP.Net manage oracle session.

---

ps. I use "Oracle.DataAccess.dll" version 4.121.2.0

Answer (score 0):

You are likely seeing connection pooling - the "using" calls dispose which returns the connection to the pool but does not close it.  You can set "pooling=false" in your connection string to confirm, but there is little reason to turn it off.

Your second loop might be acting differently because of the way oracle decreases the pool size:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/featConnecting.htm#i1006393

That said, I would just let pooling do what it is supposed to do.  The only thing I tend to add is "min pool size=0".  This makes sure the pool goes to 0 if the app is completely idle and helps protect against getting stale connections in the pool.

Answer (score -1):

IF you want to close session you should finish you call `connection.Dispose();`

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/dotnet/getstarted-c/getstarted_c_otn.htm

But why you want to close session in loop?
Open session is expensive operation, and better rule of tombs is reusing one connection in times. And Oracle allow you to use one user/pass to several sessions. May be you should think about it.

Comment: No need to call Dispose() explicitly as the using statement takes care of that

Comment: Yes , I want to reuse session but i can not optimize old code a few day(this is an old appliction) so it need some quick solution change this one before modify whole sourcecode all